# Recursively rename files while retaining all characters preceding an underscore

Tags: files, rename

I've got a need to recursively rename several thousand files on a CentOS 7 machine currently in the format of:

```
(32-64 alphanumerics)_various special characters.wav
```

In short, I would like to recursively remove the `_` up to the `.wav` extension from all files 3 levels deep (NOTE: All extensions are `.wav`)

Example:
Existing:

```
/home/user/recordings/TEST/december/157A757989F047C3AC2EC3499B4D04A5_7075276189 by user@domain.com @ 8_44_52 AM.wav

/home/user/recordings/test/october/28D1E1840DE24D9DB4CF6D1A707533F6337C2DDE_2018690759 by user@domain.com @ 1_26_55 PM.wav
```

Desired:

```
/home/user/recordings/TEST/december/157A757989F047C3AC2EC3499B4D04A5.wav

/home/user/recordings/test/october/28D1E1840DE24D9DB4CF6D1A707533F6337C2DDE.wav
```

I've searched a great deal and have seen many ways to modify other parts of the filename but not retain everything before a specific character (`_`) and the extension.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract the directory part, the file name and then the chars preceding the *first* underscore (since all files are `.wav` there's no point to save the extension in a separate variable):

```
find /home/scott/ -maxdepth 4 -type f -name '*_*.wav' -exec sh -c 'h=${1%/*}
t=${1##*/}; echo mv "$1" "${h}/${t%%_*}".wav' doom {} \;
```

remove the `echo` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

> I've searched a great deal and have seen many ways to modify other
>   parts of the filename but not retain everything before a specific
>   character (_) and the extension.

This `sed` seems to do the trick:
`sed -E 's/(.*)_[0-9].* by .*(\.wav)/\1\2/'`

```
echo "/home/user/recordings/TEST/december/157A757989F047C3AC2EC3499B4D04A5_7075276189 by user@domain.com @ 8_44_52 AM.wav" | sed -E 's/(.*)_[0-9].* by .*(\.wav)/\1\2/'
/home/user/recordings/TEST/december/157A757989F047C3AC2EC3499B4D04A5.wav
```

Testting on your other example string:

```
echo "/home/user/recordings/test/october/28D1E1840DE24D9DB4CF6D1A707533F6337C2DDE_2018690759 by user@domain.com @ 1_26_55 PM.wav" | sed -E 's/(.*)_[0-9].* by .*(\.wav)/\1\2/'
/home/user/recordings/test/october/28D1E1840DE24D9DB4CF6D1A707533F6337C2DDE.wav
```

With `sed`, you save parts of your expression with `()`, and then put them back with `\1\2`.

Comment: Thanks, I was checking the sed man and thinking there would be a way. I'll check this in my test environment. I really appreciate the response. This is for a few thousand files in several hundred directories. Will your example only do one directory at a time or will it do it recursively?

Comment: This is for one file. You have to implement this with `find` or something similar to do it recursively,

Comment: I have find working but cannot get it to get the results into sed: `code`find /home/scott/ *.wav -maxdepth 4 -type f -exec sed -E 's/(.*)_[0-9].* by .*(\.wav)/\1\2/';`code`

Comment: @don_crissti
_ not sure how to edit_
That was much closer! But it produced some unexpected changes in my test environment.  

Within the sub-directories MOST of the files were renamed as I had hoped for.

Here is an example of success:

`File: 1678FEF2B0C040B4890F537365345491_3524474135 by email@address.com @ 6_16_28 AM.wav`

`Ended up: 1678FEF2B0C040B4890F537365345491.wav` 

Here is an example of undesired result:

`File: 1606D9D38D4F4F639BD87D63AFED8194_8316440833 by  @ 7_48_05 AM_Transfer to TMS.wav`

`Ended up: 1606D9D38D4F4F639BD87D63AFED8194_8316440833 by  @ 7.wav`

Comment: So...multiple underscores in both success and fail. This is gonna be a tough one. If I HAVE to I'll go in and find the couple hundred fails and manually rename them. I wish I had more time before this project is due... it a great learning experience just trying to think about how to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Install any of the `prename` (Perl rename) implementations, for example [`File::Rename`](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/lib/File/Rename.pm) or the one from [`Unicode::Tussle`](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Unicode-Tussle-1.111/lib/Unicode/Tussle.pm). (Last I looked, CentOS didn't come with any Perl rename, only with the util-linux `rename` which can't do what you need, but this may have changed in CentOS 7.) All of them have the basic syntax `prename CODE FILENAME...` where `CODE` is some Perl code that is applied to transform each file name.

```
find /home/user/recordings/ -type f -exec prename 's!_[^/]*(\.[^./]*)$!$1!' {} +
```

Explanation for the Perl: `(\.[^./]*)$` matches the extension at the end of the name; `_[^/]*` matches everything in the file name without the directory part (no slashes) starting from the first underscore. The replacement is `$`, i.e. the part in the first and only parenthesized group.